# Check constraints in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

Is there a way to have NHibernate's SchemaExport generate check constraints defined in its .hbm.xml files? Or is that not really part of its domain?

Either way, how can I, in combination with NHibernate's SchemaExport, add check constraints to the schema it generates so as to run my unit tests properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you define your property mapping, you can define a column and identify a constraint via the check attribute.

```
<property name="count" not-null="true" >
  <column name="count" check="count &gt;= 0"/>
</property>
```

See Section 19.1 of the NHibernate [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Perfect! Also thank you for the link to the documentation, for some reason I could not find it before.

Comment: Not a problem. It can be hard to find things in the documentation sometimes.

Comment: Link to documentation is broken